# Array disappears

Tags: iphone, uipickerview

I'm in a view that has a UIPickerView. Here is where I'm making my sortedArray.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
   [super viewWillAppear:animated];

   NSMutableArray *studentNames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

   for (Student *student in course.students)
      [studentNames addObject:student.name];

   sortedArray = [studentNames sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];

   [picker selectRow:(kRowMultiplier*sortedArray.count)/2 inComponent:0 animated:NO];
}
```

I can do an `NSLog([sortedArray componentsJoinedByString:@", "]);` in these two methods and it **works**:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
```

and

```
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
```

but when I do that same trace in this method it **doesn't work** (It crashes):

```
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
```

I don't understand why the sortedArray works everywhere but in this one method.

Comment: where is the sorted array defined?

Comment: the sortedArray is defined in the header.

Comment: have you tried 
[self setSortedArray:[studentNames sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)]];

Comment: I don't even think it's a sorted array problem anymore. I believe this problems stems from not saving a student object correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From documentation of `sortedArrayUsingSelector:`:

> The new array contains references to the receiver’s elements, not copies of them.

Maybe the original strings are already released?

BTW, I see that you don't release the `studentNames` - memory leak...

Comment: I'm not sure where I messed up, but because you're the only one who gave an answer I will give you credit. And because you noticed my leak. Thanks.